# Can I add to a forked repo without adding to the origin?

Tags: git, github

Context: I forked a repo and cloned the fork to localhost. Then instructions were to run `git remote remove origin` in the terminal. I edited some of the code and am now done for the day.

Expectation: I would like to add this updated code to MY forked repo but not to the origin. I was taught to add to repos with these commands:

- `git add <name>`
- `git commit -m "Message"`
- `git push origin main`

Problem: At this time there is no remote and when I do create a remote with the URL from my forked repo and try to push, it needs an upstream.

I was taught to add the origin as the upstream, so in this case it would be the repo that I forked, but that's not what I want to do.

Comment: Did you clone your fork, or did you clone the main repo and fork from there? You only would need to remove a the remote if you did the latter. When you push, just make sure you're pushing to your forked repo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you only cloned your already forked repo, then all you really needed to do was clone that and use it like normal.

It sounds like you removed that remote in your local copy so you would need to add it back if you want to be able to update.

Verify that you have a remote set up

```
$ git remote
origin
```

If you don't have a remote set up, then you'll have to add it back.  Add a remote called `origin`:

```
$ git remote add origin [url to your repository]
```

Once that is set, you should be able to push your changes as usual.